# Show a div after hiding it in jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jQuery + UI to hide a DIV and then show it again when clicking on a particular element.

```
$(".leftnav").click(function () {
  $(".rightnav").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

I have this so far: http://jsfiddle.net/452Yx/22/

I cant work out how to get the DIV to show again by clicking the same element.

Any ideas?

thanks

Mike

Comment: thanks for your helps guys, much appreciated. It seems to be working on jsfiddle, but not on my site. any ideas? http://www.thefave.co.uk/

Comment: Your main.js file isn't being loaded/found. If you view the source and click on js/main.js, nothing shows up, so your code isn't executing.

Comment: hi, sorry thats just a blank file at the moment, nothing in there yet. the code is in the mail html file.

Comment: Also, wrap your code in the $(document).ready(function(){//yourcode});

Comment: tried that earlier, added it again. still not working. :(

Comment: Delete everything in between your script tags and copy and paste the code in my answer exactly as it is. It will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I cant work out how to get the DIV to show again by clicking the same element."

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".leftnav").toggle(function () {

        $(".rightnav").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);

    }, function(){

        $(".rightnav").show();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
$(".leftnav").click(function () {
  $(".rightnav").toggle("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

Also note that jquery toggle is not exactly the same as jqueryui toggle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use toggle. Here is something you can do with your code. You could check if object is visible. If is hide or else show.

```
$(".leftnav").click(function () {
    if($(".rightnav").is(":visible"))
      $(".rightnav").hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    else $(".rightnav").show();
});
```

But toggle is better.

Comment: thanks for your helps guys, much appreciated. It seems to be working on jsfiddle, but not on my site. any ideas? http://www.thefave.co.uk/

Comment: yep, same version. was the latest, but made same and still having problems.

Comment: hmm, not really sure how to so that tbh.

Comment: just put alert("something"); in your code.. Maybe on different places.